# Recalculate the same javascript variable on each Bootstrap carousel slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popin/modal (using [Hubspot Messenger](http://github.hubspot.com/messenger/)) that contains a  Bootstrap 3 carousel. On each slide of the carousel a different "social embed" (like facebook or [twitter embed](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/oembed)) appears and I want to resize the width of the modal/popin according to the size of the image.

What I basically do is change the width of the modal (cases of slides come from a backoffice, so using my backend language Ruby):

```
$("ul.messenger.messenger-fixed").css("width",insta_classic_size);
```

The whole code is:

```
<div class="item <% if index == 0 %>active<% end%>">      

        <% if slide['modal_slide_type'] == "instagram" %>
          <script>  
              var insta_size = Math.max( Math.floor(embedWidth), 320);                      
              $("ul.messenger.messenger-fixed").css("width",insta_size); 
          </script>

        <% elsif slide['modal_slide_type'] == "twitter" %>   

          <script> 
            var twitter_size = Math.floor(embedWidth);           
            $("ul.messenger.messenger-fixed").css("width",twitter_size); 

          </script>

       and so on... many different other types of slides...
```

My problem is that when I load the modal/popin, all the scripts are executed, that is to say in the above example the TWO blocks of  and..as expected the value of $("ul.messenger.messenger-fixed")'s width is set to the latest block being executed, here meaning twitter_size.
so even the first  block will have a $("ul.messenger.messenger-fixed")'s width' width set to twitter_size instead of what I wanted to, that is to say a width equal to insta_size.

Basically what I need is to know how to prevent the code to execute ALL the scripts or to tell him to **Recalculate the value on each slide when it becomes visible (=active)**.

I tried using some [BS carousel events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events) but failed to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not someone who has used ruby, but surely only the script inside the reached 'if' block is called? Is that not the case? Either way you could try the following;

The code initializing all of the carousel.

```
...
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
...
```

The items inside the carousel;

```
<div class="item" data-slidetype="twitter">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item" data-slidetype="instagram">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Then the following javascript;

```
myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    console.log(e.relatedTarget.dataset.slidetype);
});
```

The console will either output 'twitter' or 'instagram' dependent on the active slide. You can then use this event to trigger whichever calculations you want.

```
myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var activeSlide = e.relatedTarget.dataset.slidetype
    if ( activeSlide == "instagram" ) {
        // Insta calculations
    } else if ( activeSlide == "twitter" ) { 
        // twitter calculations
    }
});
```

This is all from a JS point of view though but maybe you can salvage something. Makes use of data attributes assigned to the various items but you could use another property or look at children if they contain the information you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.